# Ошибка: Property [...] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel

Хочу извлечь первый элемент из списка team, вместе с его работой из списка portfolio.

Ошибка:

> Property [portfolio] does not exist on this collection instance.

Portfolio.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Portfolio extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'portfolio';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'author_id');
    }
}
```

Team.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Team extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'team';

    public function portfolio()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Portfolio', 'author_id');
    }
}
```

DatabaseController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Portfolio;
use App\Team;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DatabaseController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $team = Team::find([1])->portfolio;
        return view('welcome', ['team' => $team]);
    }
}
```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$team = Team::find(2)->portfolio;
```

Передавайте в метод find() ид требуемого объекта - тогда он вернет этот объект. Если же передать массив ид (как у вас: `Team::find([1])`), то тогда он вернет коллекцию объектов, и, соответственно вы получите ошибку `Property [portfolio] does not exist on this collection instance`, потому что у коллекции, в отличие от объекта, нет такого свойства `portfolio`.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена:

```
$team = Team::where('id', '2')->first()->portfolio;
```

Мб у кого-то есть решение более лаконичное?